# Is it normal for brand new brake rotors to look a little rusty

Tags: parts, wear

By looking at these images, would you think these parts are used?
There is a very slight lip at the edge of the surface where the pads will rub.

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Comment: I wasn't sure about giving the company name, but they took good care if me so let this be a plus & not a minus for them. Adavanced Auto not only replaced them, but gave me a hefty discount too. The new ones are shiny and clean!

Comment: I'm willing to bet that Advance Auto didn't even know they were used. Likely they accepted a return of what looked to be an unopened package, but was actually a re-sealed package by a dishonest buyer.

Comment: @Shamtam That's what AAP and I both thought.

Comment: That's good service by them - opened and didn't fit is one thing but somebody was mean. Again they looked after you, magic!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They're used - you can see the marks on the center where they've been attached to a wheel. They also look scored - run your fingernail across those scatches; if you can feel the ridges, it needs resurfacing.

Have a look at a few Youtube videos on installing and cleaning new rotors, and you'll see what a new one looks like. Basically, it'll be in a plastic bag, and it will have an oily film all over it (which needs to be removed by a bedding-in procedure). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXceohslvY4 is a good example of such a video.

Brand new rotors should look like this:

[image: New Rotor]

Comment: I agree with your assessment here. Also, most new rotors have rust inhibitors on them (as well as in a bag) which prevent oxidation while they are in storage at the parts store or warehouse. They usually only form rust after the rust inhibitors are burned off, which only occurs once the disks have been used. The disks in the OP's picture *are definitely used*.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't know about "bedding in". I'll watch it before I proceed.

Comment: +1, but one thing I'll mention: bedding-in isn't to remove the oily film over the rotor. During installation, brake parts cleaner should be applied liberally to the rotors to remove all of the oily residue used to keep the rotor from rusting during packaging. Bedding-in is done after the brake install to "break-in" the pad material as well as to mate the pads to the specific surface of the rotor they are in contact with. It also should evenly distributes pad material over the surface of the rotor to make up for small imperfections in the surface of the rotor.

Comment: Those lines on the rotor surface are another giveaway. The ones on new rotors are all straight and go in every direction, but it doesn't take long for break pads wear them down into rings during use.